# Count numerical out of range events based on duration

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL and have a complex search I'm trying to make work for a customer. Given a table, I need to count the number of times a value goes out of range, in this case >5, for a period of >15 minutes.

The table has a unique entry per tag every 1 minute since early 2011 and any query is limited to 5000 results.

```
Tagname | TimeStamp               | Value
------- | ----------------------- | ----
tag1    | 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 4.67
tag2    | 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 4.66
tag3    | 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 4.68
tag1    | 2011-01-01 00:01:00.000 | 4.63
...
```

The pseudocode for what I want to do is something like

```
Count( 
  SELECT TimeStamp, Value FROM rawData WHERE rawData.Tagname = 'tag1' AND
  (Value > 5 for 15 minutes)
)
```

This is running off an ancient GE Historian 3.5 install with limited syntax. I don't need highly optimized code, just something that works with the most basic SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of GE Historian, but here is a way to think of your problem that should make it simple to solve with basic SQL:

You need to `SELECT` rows `WHERE Value > 5` AND there does not EXIST a row with the same Tagname WHERE the TimeStamp is within 15 minutes after this one, and the value is <= 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER, maybe you could try:

```
SELECT COUNT(TagName)
FROM
(
SELECT TagName,TimeStamp,Value,LAG(Value,14) OVER(PARTITION BY TagName, ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC) as TimeSpan_Value
FROM rawData
) as A
WHERE A.TagName = 'tag1' AND A.Value >5 AND A.TimeSpan_Value >5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the system doesn't have access to the LAG command. I had looked into using that originally.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with a correlated sub-query

```
declare @table table (Tagname varchar(4), TS datetime, Val decimal(3,2))
insert into @table
values
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:00:00.000',4.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:01:00.000',5.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:02:00.000',6.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:03:00.000',6.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:04:00.000',4.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:05:00.000',5.67),    --start of return rows
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:06:00.000',5.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:07:00.000',6.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:08:00.000',6.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:09:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:10:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:11:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:12:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:13:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:14:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:15:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:16:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:17:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:18:00.000',7.67),
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:19:00.000',7.67),    --15 min mark
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:20:00.000',7.67),    
('tag1','2011-01-01 00:21:00.000',7.67)




;with cte as(
select 
    t.Tagname
    ,t.TS
    ,t.Val
    ,OV = (select min(Val) from @table t2 where t2.Tagname = t.Tagname and t2.TS <= dateadd(minute,15,t.TS) and t2.TS >= t.TS)
from 
    @table t)


select
    Tagname,
    TS
from 
    cte
where Val >5 and OV > 5
```

**USING A JOIN**

```
;with cte2 as(
select 
    t.Tagname
    ,t.TS
    ,t.Val
    ,OV = min(t2.Val)
from 
    @table t
    inner join 
    @table t2 on
    t2.Tagname = t.Tagname and t2.TS <= dateadd(minute,15,t.TS) and t2.TS >= t.TS
group by
    t.Tagname
    ,t.TS
    ,t.Val)

select * 
from cte2
where val> 5 and OV > 5
```

Comment: I'll try this next time I have access to the system, it's a local only network and I'm only on-site a couple times a month. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to check back and UV / Accept if it works out for you.